# ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view

Tags: angular, components, observable, destroy, behaviorsubject

(angular 8 in use)

I have an issue currently with my code using a behaviour subject.

Component A creates another component B trough the component factory. Now, Component A subscribes to component B it's status to know when to delete it. In this case, whenever there is an error in component B, Component A will change its own status and call Component B.destroy().

However, whenever I will run this destory method, I get an error in the logs saying

`ERROR Error: ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges`

I do untach the change detector before i'm removing it, but that does not seem to help.

Here is the code:

```
createComponent(): void {
    this.logger.debug('Widget: creating component based on type provided in config.');

    this.setWidgetLoading(true);
    this.componentFactory.createComponent(this.content, this.componentConfig).subscribe((componentRef) => {

        this.componentRef = componentRef;

        this.componentRef.instance.componentStatus.subscribe((status: Status) => {
          this.setComponentStatus(status);
        });

      }, (error: Error) => {
        this.setComponentStatus(StatusFactory.createErrorStatus(error));
        this.setWidgetLoading(false);
      },
      () => {
        this.setWidgetLoading(false);
        this.logger.debug('Widget: component created based on type provided in config.');
      });

  }

setComponentStatus(status: Status): void {

 case STATUS_TYPE.ERROR:
        this.setWidgetLoading(false);
        this.componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detach();
        this.componentRef.destroy(); //componentRef references the created component B
        return;
}
```

EDIT

here are the two methods from component B

```
 ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    if (this.config.mode === ENTITY_FORM_MODE.UPDATE && !this.data) {
      this.logger.debug('EntityCreationComponent: initialized for update mode but no data provided.');
      this.setErrorStatus(ErrorFactory.createError('initialized for update mode but no data provided.'));
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    super.ngOnInit();
    this.entity = Object.assign(this.entity ? this.entity : {}, EntityFactory.createEntity(this.config.dataConfig.dataType));

    this.logger.debug('EntityCreationComponent: initialized.');
  }
```

Comment: can you please share the complete code for Component A and Component B?

Comment: I added the two methods from component B that gets destroyed. As you can see, it informs component A thats it has an error too which component A calls destroy() after it got the message trough the behaviour subject.

Comment: You forgot to unsubscribe.

`this.subscription = this.componentFactory.createComponent(this.content, this.componentConfig).subscribe(`

and unsubscribe it on destroy and before calling `createComponent` again.

`ngOnDestroy() {this.subscription.unsubscribe()}`

Answer (score 0):

Oke, somehow i fixed it. It seems due to an unknown issue, the AfterViewInit was called before a certain on change hook. I switched up the code for assinging the behaviour subject and all works well now.